# Oracle driver ojdbc6 maven dependency error in spring boot application

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to develop spring boot application which will in back-end connect to oracle db. 
For oracle db connection I have added ojdbc6 driver dependency. I already have ojdbc6 jar in .m2 folder. But still I am getting compilation error in pom.xml for ojdbc6 dependency **'Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3'**

As per solutions mentioned on various sites I tried to install ojdbc6 jar using following mvn command :
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar

But it failed saying artifact already exist:

[jar installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfK1J.gif)

[Error in pom.xml:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDF3f.gif)

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the project and/or reimporting maven dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to .m2 folder, find the path of repository/com/oracle/... and delete the content. then run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:
Download the jar, rename it according to your dependency and paste in the repository folder. For example below path and the dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

C:\Users\Elias.m2\repository\com\ibm\db2\jcc\db2jcc4\10.1